# Cisco Anyconnect: "Posture Assessment failed: Unable to load the CSD library" on Macbook Pro, M1 pro chip

Tags: apple-m1, cisco, anyconnect

I used `anyconnect-macos-4.8.01090-predeploy-k9.dmg` to install anyconnect, it only works once after I install it. (I will then connect to my company's VPN, before that it will automatically upgrade itself to version `4.10.04065` after installation, then the connection is successful).

However, once I disconnect it, subsequent connections will always fail.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this?
my Mac: MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021), M1 Pro chip

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Steps that worked for me:

1. Open Finder
2. Within Finder, on the top right, search for "Cisco"
3. Right-click on the Cisco AnyConnect Client
4. Click "Get Info"
5. Tick the checkbox "Open using Rosetta"
6. Quit & restart AnyConnect, it should work again.

Comment: OMG, Don't know why that's the case but it works! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Still valid in 2024. Cisco needs to get their act together and fix this...